# bin.gcc missing in MinGW 64 c compiler?

Tags: c++, c

so I have download c compiler from mingw but I am constantly getting gcc not found error so I saw some youtube video and they suggested to set the path for bin.gcc file but this file doesn't exit in my mingw64 folder what should I do now ?
PS : I have already tried installing it again and again few times

Comment: I suggest to follow https://www.msys2.org/

Comment: The file gcc.exe should be in bin folder. Go to mingw/bin/ and find gcc.exe. To set the directory to PATH you need to add only directory that contains gcc.exe ( in your case it would be something like "C:\mingw32\bin" ).

Answer (score 1):

Full process in Windows:

1. Download and run mingw-get-setup.exe.
2. Run MinGW installation manager's GUI, and select the packages that you wish, e.g. basic-setup, gcc, g++, gdb.
3. Add bin folder to the path environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have installed mingw (64bit edition) under `C:\mingw\mingw64` (make sure that you have selected to include gcc/g++ during installation). Then you will need to add `C:\mingw\mingw64\bin` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Now you need to start a new shell/terminal (if you have added it to your Users PATH variable) or reboot your system (if you have added it to the System PATH variable). Then you can check if gcc is available via `gcc -v`

Comment: I tried it but now it is saying fatal error no such files

Comment: Please paste your complete command line with the error output.

Comment: @Achilles73 This is the correct error message of GCC if you don't provide a source file to compile. Congratulations! You have set PATH correctly.

Comment: so how do I provide source file now and I am getting error like gcc.exe:fatal error ; no such file compilation terminated

Comment: Try the command "gcc.exe --version" to check if you can call gcc and have setup the PATH variable correctly. Afterwards you can compile sourcecode by "gcc.exe main.c -o main". You will need to create a main.c with valid c code and call gcc from within the folder where the main.c file is.